# Kazam Screenrecorder's Strange Behaviour in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, kazam

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.

While i record a video for 30 Seconds using kazam screenrecorder, its gets saved in the Video Folder as usual (Now .avi format).

But the File's Size is 3.5 GB for 30 Seconds video.

What is the issue in it ?

[I even tried installing kazam newly]

Comment: Probably depends on your settings. What settings were you using? Is there any dotfile (`.`) in your home folder related to kazam? (`ls -a | grep kazam`) You might need to remove that.

Comment: No, i don't find any . files related to kazam

Comment: yes you do it's located in the ~/.config directory. Run this command and it may fix the issue `sudo rm -R ~/.config/kazam`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, from my personal experienced, raw AVI are very big files. However, you can select other video encodings that have a smaller file size such as Webm and MP4. To do this:

Open your Kazam. On Menu:

Files -> Preferences

Select Screencast Tab

Choose Record With : VP8(Webm) or MP4

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in 14.10. Erasing the file ~/.config/kazam seemed to help.

```
sudo rm -R ~/.config/kazam
```

Also, installing these packages may help:

```
sudo apt-get install libmp4-info-perl libmp4v2-2 libxmp4 mp4h mp4v2-utils python3-pysnmp4 xmms2-plugin-mp4 python-pysnmp4 python-pysnmp4-apps
```